# Running shell script using .env file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command

I am fairly new to running scripts in UNIX/Linux. I have a .env file containing environment information and a .sh script containing folder creations etc for that environment.

How would I run the script on the environment contained in the .env file or how could I point the script to the target environment?

Would it be as easy as:

```
bash 'scriptname.sh' 'filename.env'
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to source the environment in the calling shell before starting the script:

```
source 'filename.env' && bash 'scriptname.sh'
```

In order to prevent polution of the environment of the calling shell you might run that in a sub shell:

```
(source 'filename.env' && bash 'scriptname.sh')
```

Comment: dont you also need `set -a` beforehand? Otherwise, the environment variables wont be exported and the script `scriptname.sh` will not have access to any of those. Why is this upvoted / what am I missing?

Comment: @phil294 It depends. From reading the question it seemed to me that env.sh does already use `export`. If it's only setting variables but does not export them, then `set -a` might be an option. Well, it would export all variables from the calling script, not just those from env.sh, which might or might not be desired.

Answer (score 12):

```
. ./filename.env 
sh scriptname.sh
```

First command set the env. variables in the shell, second one will use it to execute itself.

Comment: I have my .env file set up as lines of `VAR=val`. This loaded the variables properly for me.

Answer (score 9):

Create the a file with name maybe `run_with_env.sh` with below content

```
#!/bin/bash
ENV_FILE="$1"
CMD=${@:2}

set -o allexport
source $ENV_FILE
set +o allexport

$CMD
```

Change the permission to `755`

```
chmod 755 run_with_env.sh
```

Now run the bash file with below command

```
./run_with_env.sh filename.env sh scriptname.sh
```

Comment: Is possible to change somehow the `run_with_env.sh` to accept commands with pipeline, i.e. `scriptname.sh | scriptname2.sh` as the argument? I have more scripts in pipelines and I would like to set env to all of them.

Comment: very good solution ! just add the   
#!/bin/sh. 
at the top

Comment: does `sh` have `source`? i think that's a `bash` command