# How to temporarily load an env file for a single shell command, as a bash util/function/alias?

Tags: bash

Similar to [Running shell script using .env file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347533/running-shell-script-using-env-file), but I'd like to have an `xargs`-like "append usage":

```sh
xenv path/to/existing/envfile <WHATEVER COMMAND TO RUN>
```

For example, with an `envfile` on disk like:

```sh
FOOBAR="Hello Word"
```

I'd like to get:

```sh
% FOOBAR="old value"
% echo $FOOBAR
old value
% xenv path/to/envfile echo $FOOBAR
Hello World
% echo $FOOBAR
old value
```

I've tried variations like:

```sh
xenv() {
  (set -a && source "$1" && "$@")
}

xenv() {
  (set -a && source $(realpath "$1") && "$@")
}
```

Comment: You need to remove `$1` from `$@` in the function by one means or another — as in the answer, which doesn't yet explain what it is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your `xenv()`:

```
$ xenv() { (set -a && source "$1" && shift && "$@"); }
$ cat envfile
FOO='hello world'
$ FOO='old value'
$ echo $FOO
old value
$ xenv ./envfile bash -c 'echo $FOO'
hello world
$ echo $FOO
old value
$
```

Note that usage like `xenv ./envfile echo "$FOO"` does not work because `$FOO` would expand in current shell's env.