# Is it possible to use .env file at build time?

Tags: rust, environment-variables

I'm coming to Rust from the JavaScript world, where you could have a `.env` file (git-ignored), and environmental values from this file could be made available at runtime via an npm package (say, `dotenv`).

I was able to use a `dotenv` crate to make this work similarly when I just `cargo run` the project, but after I build a release version, the value of the environment variable is lost and the app panics.

I understand that `cargo` doesn't evaluate env variables at build time, and using `env!`-like macros won't work either, at least to my best understanding.

What I'm asking is this: how do I store a variable in a file (that I can gitignore), make Rust pick up values from this file, and use them at build time so that these values are available to the release-built app?

I'm sure that there's a well-established way of doing this, but I struggle to figure it out.

Comment: Try checking out “direnv”.

Comment: If there were a way to pass a string to `dotenv`, you could use `include_str` and pass the result in, but there isn't. One option is to use `option_env!` falling back to `dotenv`, and loading the [environment variables manually when you do a build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347533/running-shell-script-using-env-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the [dotenv-codegen](https://crates.io/crates/dotenv_codegen) crate that provides a `dotenv!` macro that works like the `env!` macro except it will load from a `.env` file.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not so sure this is well-established, but you can use a [build script](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) that will read the file and use [`println!("cargo:rustc-env=VAR=VALUE")`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#rustc-env) to send the environment variables to Cargo, allowing you to retrieve them in the code with [`env!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.env.html) or [`option_env!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.option_env.html).

For example, to use a `.env` file, add [`dotenv`](https://docs.rs/dotenv) to [`build-dependencies`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#build-dependencies), and use it like so in build.rs:

```rust
fn main() {
    let dotenv_path = dotenv::dotenv().expect("failed to find .env file");
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed={}", dotenv_path.display());

    // Warning: `dotenv_iter()` is deprecated! Roll your own or use a maintained fork such as `dotenvy`.
    for env_var in dotenv::dotenv_iter().unwrap() {
        let (key, value) = env_var.unwrap();
        println!("cargo:rustc-env={key}={value}");
    }
}
```